# Cakephp Validation negative amount of money

Tags: cakephp

1. I'm trying to validate a field in cakephp with a negative money amount. But it doesnt let me enter negative numbers
2. Validation doens't show the currency symbol

These are my validation rules:

```
    'TotalAmount' => array(
            'money' => array(
                    'rule' => array('money', 'left'),
                    'message' => 'Enter a valid money amount.',
                    'allowEmpty' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                    //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
            'notempty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    'message' => 'This field can not be empty',
                    //'allowEmpty' => false,
                    //'required' => true,
                    //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                    //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            )
    )
```

Comment: You could always try writing custom validation rules according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off creating your own validation rule to handle this - technically money cant be negative (but I understand your reasoning for needing it)

Check out this link:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Basically your function just needs to return true or false!